# Static error when giving the command "python manage.py collectstatic"

Tags: django, python-3.x, pythonanywhere

When I give the command "python manage.py collectstatic" it gives the following problem

```
"0 static files copied to '/home/leonard368a/leonard368a.pythonanywhere.com/static', 119 unmodified."
```

does anyone have any way to solve this?

line of command:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

]
STATIC_ROOT = "/static/"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. So what's the problem here? It just ***ignores*** the duplicate files that were already there.

Comment: how can I do this? I'm a Django beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Collectstatic** command use, when you want to deploy your project on server, command copy all static file on local to server this is main use of this command and it's also be use in local but main perpose is copy all file and put on server file manager,

> In your case you use the
>    `STATICFILEES_DIRS` and `STATIC_ROOT` are same so in local file system copy static dir to static that why you need to change `STATIC_ROOT='asset'` or `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'asset')` in your root dir

[static file configration in python any where](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/deploy/#debugging-tips)

[collect static in python any where](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/deploy/#debugging-tips)

If it work let me know

Comment: in this case, would you have to leave it like that?

STATIC_URL = '/ static /'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join (BASE_DIR, 'asset')

Comment: STATIC_URL='/static/' and add static url in `urls.py`

Comment: still has the same problem of not being able to copy the files

Comment: I was taking a look at the folders in PythonAnyWheree I ended up seeing that the "static" folder is in another path, in this case, it is not in the same path as it is on my computer, could this be the error?

Comment: can you see the link i give you, i update my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208821/discussion-between-l-b-vasoya-and-leonardo-amaral).